# Multiple exports with browserify-shim

Tags: browserify-shim

Let's say i have a js file like this

```
function a() {
    //...
}
function b() {
    //...
}
```

I want to bundle it up with browserify-shim and export both a and b. Is there a way to do so?

**EDIT.** Well it looks like it is not possible. In my case i solved issue with [browserify.transform](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#btransformtr-opts). Here's what i had in my gulpfile:

```
//...
.transform(function(f){
  if(/** check filename **/) {
    return through(
      function(data){this.queue(data + ";var c = {a:a, b:b};");},
      function(){this.queue(null);}
    );
  }
  return through();
})
//...
```

and then in browserify-shim config i export this c variable.